# Alias C enum and it's entries in C++ without C-style name prefixes

Tags: c++, c, enums, namespaces, alias

I'm writing a library with both a C and C++ API. I need to write many enums in the C API and wrap them in the C++ API.

```c
typedef enum PREFIX_SomeType
{
    PREFIX_SOME_TYPE_A,
    PREFIX_SOME_TYPE_B,
    PREFIX_SOME_TYPE_C,
} PREFIX_SomeType;
```

In the C++ wrapper header I'd like to have a similar enum without name prefixes, since the C++ wrapping API uses a namespace called PREFIX.

```cpp
namespace PREFIX
{

enum SomeType : int
{
    SOME_TYPE_A,
    SOME_TYPE_B,
    SOME_TYPE_C,
};

}
```

Since these two enums are different enums they don't cleanly convert to one another. Whenever I define a struct in the C api containing enums, I'd like to use a C++ alias.

```c
typedef struct PREFIX_ApiStruct
{
    PREFIX_SomeType type;
    // ...
} PREFIX_ApiStruct;
```

And in the C++ wrapper:

```cpp
using namespace PREFIX
{

using ApiStruct = PREFIX_ApiStruct;

}
```

But, when trying to use the C++ wrapper we cannot assign a C++ enum...

```cpp
ApiStruct instance;
instance.type = SOME_TYPE_A; // Error!
```

Is there a way to let a C++ user not write type out PREFIX_ and instead use C++ namespaces, without requiring explicit casts?

Comment: They **do** cleanly cast from one to the other; what they don't do is cleanly **convert** without a cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: Ah yes thanks @PeteBecker. So far I'm thinking to just make C++ users type out the full C enum. I'm not seeing another way.

Answer (score 1):

Does an X-MACRO help?

In a shared .h:

```
#define SOME_TYPE   \
    X(SOME_TYPE_A)  \
    X(SOME_TYPE_B)  \
    X(SOME_TYPE_C)
```

In the C part:

```
typedef enum PREFIX_SomeType
{
#define X(type) PREFIX_##type,
    SOME_TYPE
#undef X
} PREFIX_SomeType;
```

In the C++ part:

```
namespace PREFIX
{

enum SomeType : int
{
#define X(type) type,
    SOME_TYPE
#undef X
};

}
```

Comment: This is where I am currently, and this does remove the prefix, though if you try to assign to an enum (without explicitly casting) there's an error. Like in the bottom of my post's explanation to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I could come up with is using C++17 to do:

```cpp
inline constexpr PREFIX_SomeType SOME_TYPE_A = PREFIX_SOME_TYPE_A;
inline constexpr PREFIX_SomeType SOME_TYPE_B = PREFIX_SOME_TYPE_B;
inline constexpr PREFIX_SomeType SOME_TYPE_C = PREFIX_SOME_TYPE_C;
```

This does mess somewhat with syntax highlighting, but I fail to see a better alternative without re-implementing the C++ struct. This is also easy to generate via x-macro.